# Dynamically calling different Lambdas based on path parameter in API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I am trying to use API Gateway to route requests to different lambdas depending on a path parameter. I've managed to this as shown in the snippet below but I am not sure this is the best approach. I was wondering if there is a better way to this, for example by mapping a particular path parameter to a particular lambda:

```
/callDifferentLambda/firstLambdaName -> lambdaFn01
/callDifferentLambda/secondLambdaName -> lambdaFnOther
```

Snippet of my `openapi.yml` file with the working solution:

```
  /callDifferentLambda/{lambdaName}:
    post:
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: lambdaName
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true

      ....

      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        type: "aws_proxy"
        httpMethod: "POST"
        requestParameters:
          integration.request.path.lambdaName: "method.request.path.lambdaName"
        uri: "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-central-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-central-1:<account_number>:function:{lambdaName}/invocations"
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
```

Comment: your schema looks good, if it works, great!